# celerybeat set to crontab(day_of_month=1) sends task multiple times in a month

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have this task which is set to crontab(day_of_month=1). But then when it perform the tasks in continues to send task minutely which is supposed to perform once.

from my *tasks.py*

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(day_of_month=1))
def Sample():
...
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

By default crontab will run every minute so you need to specify minutes and hours.

Change `@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(day_of_month=1))` to `@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=0, hour=0, day_of_month=1))`

This would run the task only at midnight on the first day of the month.